# Is there a more efficient way to combine multiple id selectors each with a child selector in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there some way to write a jQuery selector for multiple ids that also uses the parent > child selector?

I know I can do this...

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

...or this...

```
$('#div1 > input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

...or this...

```
$('#checkbox1, #checkbox2, #checkbox3').click(function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

...but when I combine both, it gets kind of verbose.  Is there a more efficient/compact way?...

```
$('#div1 > input[type=checkbox], #div2 > input[type=checkbox], #div3 > input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Give your inputs a common class?

Comment: @j08691 That's the obvious solution. I would if I could, but I'm working on a page in a Drupal content management system where they have the styling locked down.  Any custom classes I add to my code get stripped out when I save.  Only ids are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.children()`

```
$("#div1, #div2, #div3").children("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: I only want the inputs that are immediate children of the div.  Find will keep drilling down multiple levels.  Though, .children() would probably work.

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery is actually just JavaScript, and your selectors are just strings, you could actually save them to variables and concat them together. You can take it a step further and store them into an array. For instance...

```
var section = [
    '#checkbox1',
    '#div1 > input[type=checkbox]',
    '#checkbox1, #checkbox2, #checkbox3'
];

$(section[0] + ", " + section[1] + ", " + section[2]).click(function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

Depending on your code, you could cut down the size of your selectors considerably. You could even do some cool array functions to make this an even more efficient way of grouping them.

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  I never considered making an array of selector strings.  I'll file that away for future use.  Thanks.